# Have a button to fire EGORefreshTableHeaderView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation

Im using [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh)  to get the pull-refresh effect in my `tableView`. And I added a `UIBarButtonItem` with `(IBAction)refreshBtnClicke` which can call a customized method `refreshByClickRegreshBtn:` in **EGORefreshTableHeaderView.h** to show the `EGORefreshTableHeaderView` and reload my `tableView`

**TableViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)refreshBtnClicked{

    [_refreshHeaderView refreshByClickRegreshBtn:self.tableView];

}
```

**EGORefreshTableHeaderView.h**

```
- (void)refreshByClickRegreshBtn:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

[self setState:EGOOPullRefreshLoading];
NSLog(@"scrollView.contentInset.top :%f", scrollView.contentInset.top);// it's always 0 here
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
[scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:)]) {
    [_delegate egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:self];
}
}
```

**Problem**: When there is no data in my `tableView`, `EGORefreshTableHeaderView` will always show after the `UIBarButtonItem` clicked. But once the downloaded data fills the `tableView`, `EGORefreshTableHeaderView` will never appear when I click the `UIBarButtonItem` again, even though `refreshByClickRegreshBtn:` is called. Any help is appreciated:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed by replacing  `[scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)]` into `[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -60)]` as following.

```
- (void)refreshByClickRegreshBtn:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

[self setState:EGOOPullRefreshLoading];
NSLog(@"scrollView.contentInset.top :%f", scrollView.contentInset.top);// it's always 0 here
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
//[scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -60)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:)]) {
    [_delegate egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:self];
}
}
```